# How to wrap HTML text in each new line with <li> tag?

Tags: jquery, html, list, newline

I have this code:

```
<aside id="jmfe_widget-2" class="widget widget-job_listing widget_jmfe_widget">

    <h2 class="widget-title widget-title-job_listing %s">Amenities</h2>

    Air conditioning<br>
    Free parking<br>
    Access to bathrooms<br>
    Loading dock<br>
    Elevator<br>

</aside>
```

I want to wrap these points as list items, like this:

```
<aside id="jmfe_widget-2" class="widget widget-job_listing widget_jmfe_widget">

    <h2 class="widget-title widget-title-job_listing %s">Amenities</h2>

    <li>Air conditioning</li><br>
    <li>Free parking</li><br>
    <li>Access to bathrooms</li><br>
    <li>Loading dock</li><br>
    <li>Elevator</li><br>

</aside>
```

Anyway that's possbile with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to wrap each item within a div and give it a class, like so

```
<aside id="jmfe_widget-2" class="widget widget-job_listing widget_jmfe_widget">

    <h2 class="widget-title widget-title-job_listing %s">Amenities</h2>

    <div class="item">Air conditioning</div>
    <div class="item">Free parking</div>
    <div class="item">Access to bathrooms</div>
    <div class="item">Loading dock</div>

</aside>
```

Then, do this in jQuery

```
$('.item').each(function(){
   $(this).wrap('<li></li>');       
});
```

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/tu5u0an3/2/

If you can't add any HTML, then try this

```
$( "#jmfe_widget-2" )
  .contents()
    .filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    })
  .wrap( "<li></li>" )
  .end()
.filter( "br" )
.remove();
```

This will look inside your `aside` element, get the contents, remove `<br>` tags and replace them with `<li></li>`

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/tu5u0an3/5/

Comment: I can't change the HTML. This is being generated by a third-party plugin. I need to add the list tags externally because I need to add a bullet point before each line.

Comment: I've updated my post, the new code should work fine.

Comment: Perfect Thank you, used the loop the without html one worked a charm. For advice this works perfect with br tags of ACF in textarea split lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change your html, try this:

HTML:

```
<aside id="jmfe_widget-2" class="widget widget-job_listing widget_jmfe_widget">  
    <h2 class="widget-title widget-title-job_listing %s">Amenities</h2>
    <div class="list">
        Air conditioning<br>
        Free parking<br>
        Access to bathrooms<br>
        Loading dock<br>
        Elevator
    </div> 
</aside>
```

jQuery:

```
var listHTML = $('.list').html();
var listItems = listHTML.split('<br>');
$('.list').html('');
$.each(listItems, function(i, v){
    var item = '<li>' + v + '</li>';
    $('.list').append(item);
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tq52keg7/

If you can't change the html use this solution:

HTML:

```
<aside id="jmfe_widget-2" class="widget widget-job_listing widget_jmfe_widget">
    <h2 class="widget-title widget-title-job_listing %s">Amenities</h2>
        Air conditioning<br>
        Free parking<br>
        Access to bathrooms<br>
        Loading dock<br>
        Elevator<br>
</aside>
```

jQuery:

```
var widgetHTML = $('.widget').html();
var splitWidgetHTML = widgetHTML.split('</h2>');
var listItems = splitWidgetHTML[1].split('<br>');
var widgetTitleHTML = $('.widget').find('.widget-title');
listItems.splice(listItems.length - 1,1);

$('.widget').html('');
$('.widget').append(widgetTitleHTML);
$.each(listItems, function(i, v){
    var item = '<li>' + v.trim() + '</li>';
    $('.widget').append(item);
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tq52keg7/1/

Comment: I can't change the HTML. This is being generated by a third-party plugin. I need to add the list tags externally because I need to add a bullet point before each line.

Comment: @AdnanJamil So you can't add a container?!

Comment: Nope.. I can't do anything with the HTML. That's why I need jQuery to somehow add the list tags externally.

Comment: You are awesome ;) The above accepted answer isn't working. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the list items are added to an ordered or unordered list. The example below uses vanilla JS to grab the text for the list elements and jQuery to simplify the DOM interaction.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var container = $('#jmfe_widget-2');//Grab with jQuery, life will be easier because of it
    var content = container[0].childNodes; //This is the dom node without the jQuery wrapper, gives a clean way to grab text

    var myList;
    var myItem;
    var header;
    if (content.length) {//if children found proceed
        for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            if (content[i].nodeName === '#text') {//This only grabs the items you want to build into a list
                if (content[i].textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').length) {//Ignores the empty lines
                    if (!myList) {
                        myList = $('<ul>').addClass('my-list'); //create list only if there are items to add
                    }

                    myItem = $('<li>')
                        .html(content[i].textContent)//Add the text
                        .addClass('my-list-item');

                    myItem.appendTo(myList);//Add item to list
                }
            }
            else if (content[i].nodeName === 'H2') {
                header = $(content[i]);//Make into a jQuery object for convenience
            }
        }
    }

    if (myList) {//if you have a list, replace the current content
        container.html(header);//Blow away the content and add the header back
        myList.appendTo(container);//Now add the symantically correct list back
    }
});
```